# Script to extract strings between two strings in linux

Tags: string, awk, sed

I am trying to write a little script that will let me "org-capture" articles from my rss-reader (newsboat). So my scenario is this: I will pipe the article to a script; however, the article gets piped in one line, like this:

```
Title: ABC boss quits over Australian political interference claims Author: Date: Thu, 27 Sep 2018 09:39:16 +0200 Link: https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-australia-45661871 The broadcaster's chair quits amid allegations the government leaned on him to dismiss two journalists.
```

So what I need to do is to consistently store the link and the title in a variable and then call a command with these variables (emacsclient org-protocol:/ ...)

So basically I need this:

```
TITLE="ABC boss quits over Australian political interference claims"
URL="https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-australia-45661871"
```

I considered using awk or sed, but they work best for separate lines. So, I thought maybe split the single line at 'Title:', 'Author:', 'Date:' and 'Link:' and then extract with awk/sed.

I found similar use cases and questions here, but not quite the same. I want a pretty minimal script without necessarily using python.

Am I on the right track?

Thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match():

```
$ cat tst.awk
match($0,/^Title:\s*(.*)\s+Author:\s*(.*)\s+Date:\s*(.*)\s+Link:\s*(\S+)\s+(.*)/,a) {
    printf "TITLE=\"%s\"\n", a[1]
    printf "URL=\"%s\"\n", a[4]
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
TITLE="ABC boss quits over Australian political interference claims"
URL="https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-australia-45661871"
```

I showed how to save all the other fields too so you can also do anything else you need to with your input.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/^Title: (.*) Author:.* Link: (\S+).*/TITLE="\1"\nURL="\2"/' file
```

Use pattern matching to extract the fields required. The first may contain spaces so match on the key `Author:`. The second is a string of non-space characters following the key `Link:`.